# Get Control who send to postback on Global.asax

Tags: .net, asp.net, global-asax

Can I know in `Global.asax` which control do the current postback?

Comment: @umetzu ~ Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to catch in the global.asax which control made the postaback, i sorted with this Request.Form["controlName"] but i dont know if this was the control who made the postback.

Answer (score 1):

Erm no, not in global.asax

Comment: Agreed. This sounds like the sort of thing that indicates an architecture deficiency.

Comment: definitely, but that was not my question. i think this isnt yahoo answers.